# Meteor: removing a post, and animating the other posts with _uihooks

Tags: javascript, meteor

In Meteor, when I remove a post from a collection, I’d like the posts under that post to slide up, taking the removed post’s place.

I’ve read that I should use _uihooks to do this, but I’m just not sure how to implement it.

Could somebody help me, possibly with a simple example from Meteorpad?

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this as well. I struggle with _uihooks too.

Comment: the discover meteor book has a chapter exactly going through this.

Comment: @tomsp not everybody purchased that book, and the book only covers the animation of the moving of posts. Not the removal of posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is pretty simple and you don't really require a 3rd party library to do that. I suppose that the only problem here is that `_uihooks` is not very well documented, so you're pretty much on your own to figure out how it works.

### Example

Here's the general idea:

```
Template.body.onRendered(function() {
    var container = this.$('.ui.page.grid')[0];
    container._uihooks = {
        insertElement: function(node, next) {
            // this is the default behavior
            container.insertBefore(node, next);
        },
        removeElement: function(node) {
            var $node = $(node);
            $node.removeClass('visible');
            // can't use Meteor.setTimeout here because
            // it will complain about setting timeouts
            // inside simulations ...
            setTimeout(function() {
                $node.remove();
            }, 1000);
        },
    };
});
```

There's also another hook called `movedElement` but you probably don't need it for know.

So basically, you need to grab a container element that will "listen" to changes in it's children array. When an element is inserted or removed the corresponding hooks is called. The `node` and `next` arguments represent the element of interest and his next sibling respectively.

Having a hook defined for the given action, prevents the default behavior from happening, so you're alone responsible for inserting / removing the element. But that's fine, because you have an opportunity to perform a corresponding animation before completely getting rid of the element. Here are use `css` animations attached to the `visible` class.

To see how it works in practice go here:

http://uihooks-example.meteor.com

### Further reading

The source code for the example is available on GitHub:

https://github.com/apendua/uihooks-example

If you want to understand better how the `_uihooks` API really works, look into the Meteor's source code here:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/blaze/domrange.js

### Gotchas

The `insertElement` is not called when the elements are initially rendered. So it's important to take that into account if you plan to perform an animation when a new element is inserted.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Can you go into further depth what the "node" and "next" are as arguments for each hook.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using uihooks, Percolate Studio has created an awesome package called Momentum that makes uihooks a lot easier to use (http://atmospherejs.com/percolate/momentum)! You can wrap a post template as so to make the posts underneath a deleted post slide up as so

```
{{#momentum plugin='fade'}}
  {{#each posts}}
    {{> Post}}
  {{/each}}
{{/momentum}}
```

Here is a Meteorpad example of this behavior http://meteorpad.com/pad/sGu4A4nrQ56cXywxr/Momentum%20example. Good luck!

Comment: When I say "sliding up", I mean the posts below animating upwards as a whole. You're animating the removal of the posts, which is easy. You're not having the posts underneath the removed post slide up. I hope this clarifies, thanks!

Comment: Does changing the plugin value to 'slide-height' do what you want to achieve?

Comment: Although it works, it's laggy, and I was hoping to do it vanilla JavaScript and CSS without the use of packages so I could learn more about _uihooks.